# PHP If true rerun the function until condition is false

Tags: php, laravel-5

So I have a function that creates random string of characters, something like this:

```
 function createToken($len = 5) {
        $set = '123456789abcdefghijkmnpqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ';
        $setLen = strlen($set);
        $token = '';
        for ($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++) {
            $token .= $set[rand(0, $setLen - 1)];
        }
        return $token;
    }
```

Now I need to run this function and check if the return token is already in the database. Since I'm using Laravel I can check that with:

```
$modelName->whereToken($token)->exists()
```

And it will return true or false, now if it returns true I need to rerun the function and do the generation again then do the if exists again and do that over and over until it finds one that returns false on ->exists().

Comment: "Now I need to run..."  - this plus the subject line were pretty self-explanatory to others, no need to troll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 function createToken($len = 5) {
    do {
        $set = '123456789abcdefghijkmnpqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ';
        $setLen = strlen($set);
        $token = '';
        for ($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++) {
            $token .= $set[rand(0, $setLen - 1)];
        }
    }
    while($modelName->whereToken($token)->exists());
    return $token;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a do-while loop:

```
do {
  $token = createToken();
} while($modelName->whereToken($token)->exists())

//Your token is unique
```

Don't forget to add a `unique` index onto your database table https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/migrations#indexes

Comment: The "add a unique index" is a great suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `do...while` loop. the syntax is like this:

```
do {
code to be executed;
} while (condition is true);
```

So in your case, the code would be something like this:

```
do {
  $token = createToken();
} while( $modelName->whereToken($token)->exists() )
```

Comment: Little bit more help would be needed? Like do I say do {function here} while {$modelName->whereToken($token)->exists()}?